# How to read data from a hash in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have the following XML file:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<preferences>
    <font role="console">
        <fname>Courier</fname>
        <size>9</size>
    </font>
    <font role="default">
        <fname>Times New Roman</fname>
        <size>14</size>
    </font>
    <font role="titles">
        <fname>Helvetica</fname>
        <size>10</size>
    </font>
</preferences>
```

I managed to read it and dump it out. Now I am supposed to read all the key value pairs.

Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
# use module
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;

my $data = XMLin('test.xml');

# print Dumper(%data);


while ( my ($key, $value) = each(%$data) ) {
    print "$key => $value\n";
}
```

Nothing prints inside the loop... What could be the problem? I am new to this and wrote my Hello World script and this all in the same day, so I will take any advice on the code.

This works just fine:

```
my $data = XMLin('test.xml');
print Dumper($data);
```

And it gives me:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'font' => [
                    {
                      'fname' => 'Courier',
                      'role' => 'console',
                      'size' => '9'
                    },
                    {
                      'fname' => 'Times New Roman',
                      'role' => 'default',
                      'size' => '14'
                    },
                    {
                      'fname' => 'Helvetica',
                      'role' => 'titles',
                      'size' => '10'
                    }
                  ]
        };
```

I am guessing that inside the `while` loop I need to loop through each of the arrays. Am I right?

Comment: count me as an idiot and explain what you are pointing to ?

Comment: For starters, make a habit out of including `use strict` in all your code.  In this case (after you changed the line declaring `$data =...` to `my $data =...`), it would complain that you didn't declare `%data` -- which would help point you in the right direction immediately.  :-)

Comment: What is it you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: `$data` is a scalar reference, not a hash, and it couldn't be one because of the `$` sigil.

Comment: i have updated the code with the following output ...font => ARRAY(0x1f6e834)   i am pretty sure i am doing something horribly wrong inside the loop since it is printing a reference and not the value

Comment: @ash That particular key is an array reference. It needs to be dereferenced too. If your values have different types, you may need to do some type checking. But why not print them with [Data::Dumper](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data::Dumper)? E.g. `print Dumper $data`.

Comment: my $data = XMLin('test.xml');

  print Dumper($data);

Comment: @ash Exactly. Doesnt that work?

Comment: see my updated question ..added the output to it ..really sorry for this mess...i am pretty sure i will be kicked out soon for asking these questions ..

Comment: @ash I am sure you won't get kicked out. What you have there is just one key-value pair in the main hash. The value is a reference to an array. The array contains a list of hashes. Phew! You can see by the `{` or `[` if it is an array or a hash.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
use strict;
```

Is your friend. It would have told you:

```
Global symbol "%data" requires explicit package name
```

What you want is `%$data`

In other words: `$data` and `%data` counts as two different variables.

Update:

As you changed the whole question, my answer makes little sense now.. As does your question. You have printed it. What else do you need?

If you wanted to print that structure, you'd need something like (untested):

```
for my $key1 (keys %$data) {
    for my $array_value (@{ $data->{$key1} }) {
        for my $key2 (keys %$array_value) {
            print "$key2 => $array_value->{$key2}\n";
        }
    }
}
```

If you wanted to access a value directly:

```
print $data->{font}[0]{'fname'}
```

You'll need to experiment to get what you need. In the Data::Dumper output, you can easily see which values are hashes and which are arrays:

```
$VAR1 = {   # The curly bracket denotes a beginning hash 
          'font' => [     # Square bracket = array begins
                    {     # The first array element is a hash 
                      'fname' => 'Courier',   # Inside the hash
                      'role' => 'console',
                      'size' => '9'
                    },    # Hash ends
                    {     # Next array value, new hash begins
                      'fname' => 'Times New Roman',
                      'role' => 'default',
                      'size' => '14'
                    },
                    {
                      'fname' => 'Helvetica',
                      'role' => 'titles',
                      'size' => '10'
                    }
                  ]     # Array ends
        }; # Hash ends
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
 while ( my ($key, $value) = each(%$data) ) {      
   ....
```